# PDCurses blank character

Tags: c++, pdcurses

I am trying to create a rougelike, and I am using windows for the different layers. The bottom most one is the map, and the one above that is the entity layer. I have the player character, and I want to move them around on the screen. I am printing a new @ (the way the player is represented) to where they move, and I am trying to put a blank space to where the character was, so that you can see the map layer where before you couldn't. I tried using NULL, but it outputs ^@. Any idea what I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a blank character, `' '`, or if you prefer just `32` or `0x20`.

NULL is actually defined as:

```
#define NULL 0
```

So you are writing the character with ASCII code 0, that is a NUL character, sometimes represented as Ctrl+@, or ^@.

Comment: The problem with using ' ' or 32 is that it leaves a space, essentially not displaying the background. So instead of say the map layer having a white item, it would just become a black square.

Comment: Oh, I see. Not sure but I think that PDCurses does not have transparent windows. And they just happen to work the first time by chance because the foremost layer is not redrawn or something. If that's the case you should check which character is in the layer behind and draw it in the place. But if you do that, you don't need layers in the first place!

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. I guess if there is no way to get blanks then I'll just use that.

Answer (score 0):

On modern day machines clearing the screen and redrawing the whole screen completely after each edit would probably not cause too much performance issues. I know it's not the most optimal solution, but it gets rid of that kind of trail artifacts for good.